# String equality fails while testing with escaping regex special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, jestjs

I am testing a function where it returns a regex escaped version of special characters of the string and hence in test I am testing it with if it `equals to` the escaped string, but it fails with saying

```
Expected value to match:
  "4**2"
Received:
  "4\\*\\*2"
```

This is the test I have written:

```
describe("escapeRegExp", () => {
  // required for quotes test
  test("Escapes all RegExp characters", () => {
    expect(escapeRegExp("4**2")).toMatch("4\*\*2");});
```

where `escapeRegExp` function returns `"4\*\*2"` but it expects it to be `"4**2"`.

But when I use

`expect(escapeRegExp("4**2")).toMatchSnapshot("4\*\*2");` it works fine.

Any idea why it fails while checking it with `.toBe` or `toEqual()` ??

Is there any other field/argument that I have to add to make it work with `toEqual` or `toMatchSnapshot` is the way to go for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"4\*\*2"` is a string containing no backslashes at all, `4**2` (because `\*` is `*` — since `\*` isn't a defined escape sequence in a string literal, and `*` doesn't need to be escaped in a string literal, the `\` is ignored). You meant `"4\\*\\*2"`, which is the string `4\*\*2`. E.g.:

```
describe("escapeRegExp", () => {
  // required for quotes test
  test("Escapes all RegExp characters", () => {
    expect(escapeRegExp("4**2")).toMatch("4\\*\\*2");});
```

Note that the string you pass [`toMatchSnapshot`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchsnapshotoptionalstring) is an optional snapshot **name**. You don't use `toMatchSnapshot` to test literal values (you use `toMatch`). More about snapshot testing [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html#snapshot-testing-with-jest).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware that `*` is something not a part to be escaped literal but that was part of the question to escape all special characters.

Comment: also could you please add in the answer the difference between `toBe` vs `toEqual` and `toMatch`

Comment: @warl0ck: The documentation covers that.